# Conditional variance of the absolute sum of zero-mean i.i.d. random variables

Tags: variance

*Why does the following conditional variance formula hold, and does it hold in general?*

$$\text{Var} \left( \left \vert \sum^n_{i=1} U_i \right \vert \, \middle | \,D_n \right) = n \text{Var}(U_i \vert D_n).$$

Here $U_i$ are zero-mean independent and identically distributed random variables, and nothing more about their distribution is stated. Further information on $U_i$ and $D_n$ is provided below.

I am comfortable with the standard result that for i.i.d. random variables $X_i$,

$$\text{Var} \left( \sum^n_{i=1} X_i \right) = \sum^n_{i=1} \text{Var}(X_i) = n \text{Var}(X_i),$$

but the presence of the absolute values in the formula of interest has thrown me.

---

**Further information on $U_i$ and $D_n$.**

In response to the helpful comments and answer by [James Martin](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/73005/james-martin) and [Ben](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/173082/ben), it is clear that the equation does not hold in general, and that additional context on the $U_i$ and $D_n$ is required. Here is an extract of the proof where the equation is used:

> [image]
> [image]

Where $D_n = {(X_1, Y_1,), \dots, (X_n, Y_n)}$ and $D_n' = (X_1', Y_1'), \dots (X_n', Y_n')$ are two sets of i.i.d. random variables sampled from unknown joint distribution $D_n, D_n' \overset{i.i.d}{\sim} P(X, Y)$. The conditional expectation in $U_i$ is such that $\mathbb{E}_{D_n' | D_n}[\cdot \vert D_n]$. $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \{0, 1 \}$ is a classifier function , while $\tilde{f}$ is a random classifier function, dependent on $D_n$.

The argument comes from the proof of the [Vapnik-Chervonenkis inequality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_theory#/Theorem_(VC_Inequality)) in an expository note by [Robert Nowak (2009)](https://nowak.ece.wisc.edu/SLT09/lecture19.pdf), following the strategy of [Devroye,  Györfi and Lugosi (1996)](https://www.szit.bme.hu/%7Egyorfi/pbook.pdf#page=210) in their proof of Glivenko-Cantelli theorem.

Comment: The right-hand side doesn't seem well-defined, without further assumptions on the joint distribution of the random variables involved. Do you want to assume that given $D_n$, the variables $U_i$ are exchangeable, or something like that? Otherwise you don't have e.g. Var$(U_1|D_n)$=Var$(U_2|D_n)$ in general. Or you could replace the right-hand side by $\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}(U_i|D_n)$.

Comment: In the case $n=1$, it's not true unless (loosely speaking) $D_1$ tells you the sign of $U_1$. That's because $\text{Var}(|X|)=\text{Var}(X)$ is equivalent to $E(X)=\pm E(|X|)$, which needs $X$ to be either non-negative with probability 1, or non-positive with probability 1.

Comment: @James Martin. From your comment and Ben's answer, it's clear that the equation doesn't hold in general. On whether one can assume that given $D_n$, the $U_i$ are exchangeable, I have added additional context directly from the source. My understanding of the author's exposition is that perhaps there is an assumption that $U_i$ are conditionally i.i.d. given $D_n$, but to be honest, I'm not sure. I would appreciate your input on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$
In response to the edited version.

I think there's a glitch in that the "$=$" sign ought to be a "$\geq$" sign. With that change, everything seems to be (at least locally) OK.

A general fact is that $\Var(|X|)\leq \Var(X)$ for any random variable $X$. (Since $\Var(X)-\Var(|X|)=E(|X|)^2 - E(X)^2$,
and $|E(X)|\leq E(|X|)$.)

So (applying the above conditional on $D_n$) we get that $\Var\left(|\sum_{i=1}^n U_i| \big| D_n\right)
\leq
\Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \big| D_n\right)$.

Now we use the asserted fact (first line of the excerpt you quoted) that, conditional on $D_n$, the $U_i$ are i.i.d. (N.B. it's important that the $U_i$ are i.i.d. *conditional on $D_n$*; this is a different statement from saying that that $U_i$ are unconditionally i.i.d.)

That gives us that
$\Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n U_i \big| D_n\right)
=
\sum_{i=1}^n\Var\left( U_i \big| D_n\right)
=
n\Var\left(U_1\big|D_n\right)$.

Finally the next line is using the fact that $\Var(U_1\big| D_n)\leq 1/4$ (because conditional on $D_n$, $U_1$ is a shift of a Bernoulli random variable, and any Bernoulli random variable has variance at most $1/4$).

Answer (score 3):

Your equation doesn't hold in general.  As a simple counter-example, consider random variables that are conditionally IID with distribution $\mathbb{P}(U_i=-1|D_n) = \mathbb{P}(U_i=1|D_n)=\tfrac{1}{2}$.$^\dagger$  In this simple case you get:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(U_1 + U_2 | D_n) 
&= (-2) \cdot \frac{1}{4} + 0 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = 0, \\[12pt]
\mathbb{V}(U_1 + U_2 | D_n) 
&= (-2)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} + 0^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 2^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = 2, \\[12pt]
\mathbb{E}(|U_1 + U_2| | D_n) 
&= |-2| \cdot \frac{1}{4} + |0| \cdot \frac{1}{2} + |2| \cdot \frac{1}{4} = 1, \\[12pt]
\mathbb{V}(|U_1 + U_2| | D_n) 
&= (|-2|-1)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} + (|0|-1)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + (|2|-1)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = 1, \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$

so you have:

$$\mathbb{V}(|U_1 + U_2| | D_n) = 1 \neq 2 = \mathbb{V}(U_1 + U_2 | D_n).$$

In fact, as a general rule (stated here unconditionally but it also holds conditionally), you get:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V} \Bigg( \bigg| \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \bigg| \Bigg) 
&= \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \bigg| \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \bigg| ^2 \Bigg) - \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \bigg| \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \bigg| \Bigg)^2  \\[6pt]
&\leqslant \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \bigg| \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \bigg| ^2 \Bigg) - \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \Bigg)^2  \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \bigg) ^2 \Bigg) - \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \Bigg)^2  \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{V} \Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{V}(U_i) + \sum_{i \neq j} \mathbb{C}(U_i,U_j). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

In regard to your updated information, the result still does not hold with the additional information.  (And indeed, the additional information shows that the situation is just a scaled version of what I have described above, so the result is generally *false* in that case.)  It appears to me that this is probably just an error in the proof, using an invalid step.  Substiting the correct inequality in the erroneous step still gives a valid proof, so the proof itself still works once corrected.

---

$^\dagger$ You haven't given us any information on what $D_n$ is, so it is essentially irrelevant here.  Since you haven't told us anything about $D_n$ you can just posit that the values for $U_i$ are marginally IID and that $D_n$ is some irrelevant variable that is independent of these.

Comment: +1. Thanks again Ben, this is really useful for me pedagogically. In particular, the tacit reminder that I should try and construct counter-examples when faced with a questionable expression rather than staring blankly at it. I have edited my question to remedy the absence of context which you have brought up, rather than asking a new question with updated context, as another member has enquired for this.

Comment: Yeah, in fairness though, constructing counter-examples is easier said than done sometimes.  I have a fair bit of "intuition" (read: long experience) for these types of problems so the counter-example comes immediately to mind.  Without that experience it can be hard to intuitve how to form a counter-example, and staring blankly then becomes the *de facto* method.

Comment: Actually, in term of methodological approach, the first important thing here was to recognise that with the information given, conditioning on $D_n$ was irrelevant, and so you are essentially asking a simpler problem --- i.e., the question would be exactly the same without the conditioning.  Sometimes if you can simplify the *statement* of a problem then that helps to see possible pathways to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a new answer looking at the later question supplemented by your additional information.  This new answer should be seen as augmenting my previous general observations in the other answer.*

With the new information added to the question, you now have a specific distribution for the values under consideration.  Suppose we define the parameter $\theta = \mathbb{P}(\tilde{f}(X_i') \neq Y_i'|D_n)$ and note that this quantity is fixed for all $i$.$^\dagger$  From the information specified in the excerpt, we have the conditional distribution:

$$U_1,...,U_n | D_n \sim \text{IID Bern}(\theta) - \theta,$$

which gives $\sum_{i=1}^n U_i | D_n \sim \text{Bin}(n, \theta) - n \theta$.
Consequently, we get:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \Bigg( \bigg| \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \bigg| \Bigg| D_n \Bigg)
&= \sum_{k=0}^n |k-n\theta| \cdot \text{Bin}(k|n, \theta) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n \theta \rfloor} (n\theta-k) \cdot \text{Bin}(k|n, \theta) + \sum_{k=\lfloor n \theta \rfloor+1}^n (k-n\theta) \cdot \text{Bin}(k|n, \theta), \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

and:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V} \Bigg( \bigg| \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \bigg| \Bigg| D_n \Bigg)
&= \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \bigg)^2 \Bigg| D_n \Bigg) - \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \bigg| \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \bigg| \Bigg| D_n \Bigg) ^2\\[6pt]
&= n \theta (1-\theta + n\theta) \\[6pt]
&\quad + \Bigg( \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n \theta \rfloor} (n\theta-k) \cdot \text{Bin}(k|n, \theta) + \sum_{k=\lfloor n \theta \rfloor+1}^n (k-n\theta) \cdot \text{Bin}(k|n, \theta) \Bigg)^2. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

The latter quantity is not generally equivalent to:

$$\mathbb{V} \Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^n U_i \Bigg| D_n \Bigg)
= n \mathbb{V}(U_i|D_n)
= n \theta (1-\theta),$$

so this step in the paper appears to be wrong to me.  Most likely, the author meant to assert the inequality $\mathbb{V}(| \sum U_i | |D_n) \geqslant n \mathbb{V}(U_i|D_n)$ here rather than asserting equivalence (which is wrong).  The overall proof still works if you use the inequality relation instead, so this is just one of those cases where a step in the proof is written incorrectly, but the proof itself still works.

---

$^\dagger$ The information specifies that the values $U_1,...,U_n | D_n$ are IID, which can only be the case if the quantity $\theta$ is fixed over all $i=1,...,n$.